# Spring @GeneratedValue annotations not working for Auto increment field

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, scaffolding, myeclipse

I use Scaffolding in MyEclipse to generate Web Application project, using spring MVC and MySQL database. Please give me some clues to solve problem bellow.

I get problem with id primary key. It doesn't auto increment event if i use: 
*@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)*

I have several tables with the primary key set to AUTO_INCREMENT. Like this example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ehealthdb`.`timestamp` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `login_date` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  `logout_date` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  `create_date` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `update_date` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  `isActive` TINYINT(1) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When I try to use the save using the generated post URL and the following json payload:

```
{
 "loginDate":"1374839856000",
 "logoutDate":"1374839856000",
 "createDate":"1374839856000",
 "updateDate":"1374839856000",
 "isActive":true
}
```

> *Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class
>   must be manually assigned before calling save():
>   ehealth.domain.Timestamp*

I think this is caused by a missing @GeneratedValue, which scaffolding has not created on my primary keys. I had to add it in manually like below:

But It's still not work. It's still get error.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) //add this 
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@XmlElement
Integer id;
```

Comment: Is this not working when you do: @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id") ??

Comment: Yes, It's not working. 
even I try :
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)

Comment: I tried this using the steps mentioned (created table, scaffolded, added @GeneratedValue annotation) and had no problem. Can you try adding a row manually (with an SQL statement, and commit) without the ID value and check that it works?

Comment: @TonyWeddle Hi, Thank for your help. 
If i try with SQL statement, It works normally. 

--- Now I just found out that, If I post object with id=0, It'll auto increase in database.

Comment: So, just to confirm; if you have an object already in the table (with ID=0, in your case) then you can save new objects without setting the ID value. Is that right? If so, then I guess you are all set, though, as I say, I didn't see a problem even with an empty table. My tests were on Linux but I don't know if that is significant. My MySql version is 5.5.47.

Comment: No, It's not like that. I mean I need to send ID=0 for each time when I want to insert object to database.

Comment: May sound dumb but are you using the correct dialect in hibernate config? IDENTITY should work...

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean correct dialect in hibernate config ? I don't know. I'm not sure because everything is generated by myeclipse. 

So now, I can solve this problem by set value 0 to ID whenever I save an object to database, then id value is generated in DB and assign to ID field. 
I don't need @GeneratedValue.. annotation.

Comment: Lay Leangsros, thanks for the confirmation. I see you're using the MyEclipse support forums too, so we can handle any follow up there. For my part, I don't see the problem, though setting ID to 0 works as well as not setting it, in the scaffolded web page for a new timestamp.

Comment: @TonyWeddle Really ? So you mean that it works without setting ID value to 0 ?? 
So I still have problem with it, right ? 
Yeah, i don't want to set ID to 0 because it doesn't make sense for me. :(

Comment: Yes, if I don't enter a value in the ID field, the timestamp record gets added to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to set the ID field at all. It's handled automatically.

Use @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY). Make sure your Persistence.xml has

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
```

Should probably be using Hibnerate version 4 or 5.

Also, I've never seen `FetchType` on an ID column. Remove this.

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

I do this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Also, probably should understand the full setup. What version of Spring?

Comment: Thank, 
now, I can solve this problem by set value 0 to ID whenever I save an object to database, then id value is generated in DB and assign to ID field. I don't need @GeneratedValue.. annotation. 

Those @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) is generated by myeclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the following:

```
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Those are all default values, so there is no need to put that there.
I'm not sure it that will solve your problem though.

Comment: Thank, now, I can solve this problem by set value 0 to ID whenever I save an object to database, then id value is generated in DB and assign to ID field. I don't need @GeneratedValue.. annotation.